# How to play a /joint_state bag file

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recorded a joint_state bag file and I want to replay the same motion as the one recorded. Is it possible? and how would you do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37299/how-to-play-a-/joint_state-bag-file/) by [mamoun](https://answers.ros.org/users/2715/mamoun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-26**:
What do you mean with replay? Do you just want to play back the bag (rosbag play) or do you want your robot to execute the same trajectory?

**Comment by [mamoun](https://answers.ros.org/users/2715/mamoun/) on 2012-06-26**:
to execute the same trajectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any way to re-play a trajectory that has been recorded out of the box. That problem is actually highly robot-specific anyway since at least on the PR2, the joint_state topic contains basically all encoder values of the robot. This includes the position of both arms, the head and the wheels.

However, it should be doable with a little bit of work. First, do a `rosbag record /joint_states`. Then, I would use the rosbag [C++](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/rosbag/html/c++/) or [Python](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/rosbag/html/python/) API to read the data and generate goals for the different robot controllers. For the arms, you can generate joint_trajectory action goals and send them to the corresonding arm controllers. See [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20using%20the%20Joint%20Trajectory%20Action) tutorial. For the head, you probably have to define your own joint_trajectory_controller that just controls the pan and tilt joints. After building up the joint_trajectory_messages, just send the goals at the same time to the action servers. Subsequent calls do the different action client's send_goal methods should be fine there.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you rosbag play the bagfile you recorded, the trajectory will be slightly different from the real one. That's because hardware is not perfect.
To execute the same trajectory from the bagfiles make the joint servomotors listen to the joint_state topic played from the bagfile.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-27**:
I don't think this is a good idea since the joint_state topic is not meant for controlling joints but for publishing the current positions/velocities/efforts of joints.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2012-06-27**:
If the reference signal that is driving your controller is exposed as a ros topic, you should probably record that to the bag, and not joint_states.